# Scala Combine Sequences into triples

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, zip, sequence

I have 3 IndexedSequences and I could like to combine them as follows:

```
indSeq1 = (a,b,c)
indSeq2 = (1,2,3)
indSeq3 = (!,@,#)

result:([a,1,!],[b,2,@],[c,3,#])
```

I used zipped but I get `([a,b,c],[1,2,3],[!,@,#])`
How do I do this in scala, I want the output to be a IndexedSequence too.

Answer (score 2):

This is not what *I* get when I do it:

```
scala> val indSeq1 = Seq('a', 'b', 'c')
indSeq1: Seq[Char] = List(a, b, c)

scala> val indSeq2 = Seq(1,2,3)
indSeq2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val indSeq3 = Seq('!', '@', '#')
indSeq3: Seq[Char] = List(!, @, #)

scala> (indSeq1, indSeq2, indSeq3).zipped
res30: scala.runtime.Tuple3Zipped[Char,Seq[Char],Int,Seq[Int],Char,Seq[Char]] = scala.runtime.Tuple3Zipped@9789aa5f

scala> res30.toSeq
res31: Seq[(Char, Int, Char)] = Stream((a,1,!), ?)

scala> res30.toList
res32: List[(Char, Int, Char)] = List((a,1,!), (b,2,@), (c,3,#))

scala> res30.toIndexedSeq
res33: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Char, Int, Char)] = Vector((a,1,!), (b,2,@), (c,3,#))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use method `invert` on `Tuple3` as following:

```
scala> val s1 = IndexedSeq('a', 'b', 'c')
s1: IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(a, b, c)

scala> val s2 = Seq(1, 2, 3)
s2: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val s3 = Seq('!, '@, '#)
s3: Seq[Symbol] = List('!, '@, '#)

scala> (s1, s2, s3).invert
res0: IndexedSeq[(Char, Int, Symbol)] = Vector((a,1,'!), (b,2,'@), (c,3,'#))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running transpose after zipped.